# How to check if a STDIO stream is gzipped and consequently gunzip it in the same stream

Tags: linux, bash, stream, pipe, mime-types

I have the following (simplified) situation with bash:

A stream of data comes in that is gzipped. Sometimes however, the data has been double gzipped by accident so what I would have to do then is to `...incoming stream... | gunzip | gunzip | ...continue process...` . But only when I am sure that the output of the first gunzip is yet another gzipped datastream.

My initial thought was:

```
echo "My plain text" | gzip | gzip | gunzip | if [ $(mimetype -b --stdin ) == 'application/gzip' ]; then zcat; else cat; fi
```

but this leads to an empty stdin for the second gunzip (`gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`). My suspicion is that the stream can only be read once and that `mimetype` has already finished it therefor leading to an empty input to zcat.

The working of the script can be checked with:

```
echo "My plain text" | gzip | gzip | gunzip | if [ 'application/gzip' == 'text/plain' ]; then cat; else zcat; fi
```

which runs fine.

What I'd like to find out:

1. Is the assumption correct that you can only process the stream once?
2. What could be a way forward without saving the data to hard-disk in between?

Comment: Your suspicion is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zless` instead of `zcat`. If its input isn't compressed, it will pass it through unchanged (this allows you to use a single run of `zless` with a mixture of compressed and uncompressed files). It's normally an interactive utility, but if the output is not a terminal it's just a filter.

```
echo "My plain text" | gzip | gzip | zless | zless
```

Comment: This is much better than I hoped for, thx.

Comment: It's annoying that `zcat` isn't smart enough to do this itself.

Comment: This is curious from the man page: "Zless  does  not  work with compressed data that is piped to it via standard input; it requires that input files be specified as arguments.  To read compressed data from a pipe, you can use ...|gunzip|less instead of ...|zless."

Comment: I tried `echo foo | gzip | zless` and it worked.

Comment: I know. guess the man-page needs an update...